# Read HTML Table from Greyhound via R

Tags: html, r, web-scraping

I'm trying to read the HTML data regarding Greyhound bus timings. [An example can be found here.](http://bustracker.greyhound.com/routes/4511/I/Chicago_Amtrak_IL-Cincinnati_OH/4511/10-26-2016) I'm mainly concerned with getting the schedule and status data off the table, but when I execute the following code:

```
library(XML)

url<-"http://bustracker.greyhound.com/routes/4511/I/Chicago_Amtrak_IL-Cincinnati_OH/4511/10-26-2016"
greyhound<-readHTMLTable(url)

greyhound<-greyhound[[2]]
```

This just produces the following table:

[image]

I'm not sure why it's grabbing data that's not even on the page, as opposed to the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not retrieve the data using `readHTMLTable` because the traject result are sent as javascript script. So you should select that script and parse it to extract the right information.

Her a solution , that do this :

1. Extract the javascript script that contain the json data
2. extract the json data from the script using regular expression
3. parse the json data to an R list
4. Reshape the resulted list into a table ( data.table here)

The code looks maybe short but it is really compact ( it takes me an hour to do produce it)!

```
library(XML)
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
library(data.table)
dc <- htmlParse(GET(url))
script <- xpathSApply(dc,"//script/text()",xmlValue)[[5]]

res <- strsplit(script,"stopArray.push({",fixed=TRUE)[[1]][-1]
dcast(point~name,data=rbindlist(Map(function(x,y){
                       x <- paste('{',sub(');|);.*docum.*',"",x))
                       dx <- unlist(fromJSON(x))
                       data.frame(point=y,name=names(dx),value=dx)
                     },res,seq_along(res))
,fill=TRUE)[name!="polyline"])
```

the table result :

```
 point category direction     id              lat                   linkName               lon
1:     1        2     empty 562310  41.878589630127          Chicago_Amtrak_IL -87.6398544311523
2:     2        2     empty 560252 41.8748474121094                 Chicago_IL -87.6435165405273
3:     3        1     empty 561627 41.7223281860352 Chicago_95th_&_Dan_Ryan_IL -87.6247329711914
4:     4        2     empty 260337 41.6039199829102                    Gary_IN -87.3386917114258
5:     5        1     empty 260447 40.4209785461426             Lafayette_e_IN -86.8942031860352
6:     6        2     empty 260392 39.7617835998535            Indianapolis_IN  -86.161018371582
7:     7        2     empty 250305 39.1079406738281              Cincinnati_OH -84.5041427612305
                                              name                   shortName ticketName
1:        Chicago Amtrak: 225 S Canal St, IL 60606          Chicago Amtrak, IL        CHD
2:            Chicago: 630 W Harrison St, IL 60607                 Chicago, IL        CHD
3: Chicago 95th & Dan Ryan: 14 W 95th St, IL 60628 Chicago 95th & Dan Ryan, IL        CHD
4:                   Gary: 100 W 4th Ave, IN 46402                    Gary, IN        GRY
5:           Lafayette (e): 401 N 3rd St, IN 47901           Lafayette (e), IN        XIN
6:       Indianapolis: 350 S Illinois St, IN 46225            Indianapolis, IN        IND
7:          Cincinnati: 1005 Gilbert Ave, OH 45202              Cincinnati, OH        CIN
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that explained a lot of where I was going wrong. I also see from @Michael Griffiths comment how the stopArray itself is storing the data. From that it makes sense how the Greyhound website is populating most of the values in their table (such as the stop name and address).

Looking at the source code, I'm having trouble pinpointing where exactly the website's grabbing the Scheduled and Status timings from.

Answer (score 0):

As @agstudy notes, the data is *rendered* to HTML; it's not delivered via HTML directly from the server. Therefore, you can (a) use something like `RSelenium` to scrape the rendered content, or (b) extract the data from the `<script>` tags that contain the data.

To explain @agstudy's work, we observe that the data is contained in a series of `stopArray.push()` commands in one of the (many) script tags. For example:

```
stopArray.push({
  "id" : "562310",
  "name" : "Chicago Amtrak: 225 S Canal St, IL 60606",
  "shortName" : "Chicago Amtrak, IL",
  "ticketName" : "CHD",
  "category" : 2,
  "linkName" : "Chicago_Amtrak_IL",
  "direction" : "empty",
  "lat" : 41.87858963012695,
  "lon" : -87.63985443115234,
  "polyline" : "elr~Fnb|uOmC@@nG?XBdH@rC?f@?P?V@`AlAAn@A`CCzBC~BE|CEdCA^Ap@A"
});
```

Now, this is `json` data contained inside each function call. I tend to think that if someone has gone to the work of formatting data in a machine-readable format, well golly we should appreciate it!

The `tidyverse` approach to this problem is as follows:

1. Download the page using the `rvest` package.
2. Identify the appropriate `script` tag to use by employing an `xpath` expression that searches for all `script` tags that contain the string `url =`.
3. Use a regular expression to pull out everything inside each `stopArray.push()` call.
4. Fix the formatting of the resulting object by (a) separating each block with commas, (b) surrounding the string by `[]` to indicate a `json` list.
5. Use `jsonlite::fromJSON` to convert into a `data.frame`.

Note that I hide the `polyline` column near the end, since it's too large to previous appropriately.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(jsonlite)

url <- "http://bustracker.greyhound.com/routes/4511/I/Chicago_Amtrak_IL-Cincinnati_OH/4511/10-26-2016"
page <- read_html(url)

page %>%
    html_nodes(xpath = '//script[contains(text(), "url = ")]') %>%
    html_text()  %>%
    str_extract_all(regex("(?<=stopArray.push\\().+?(?=\\);)", multiline = T, dotall = T), F) %>% 
    unlist() %>%
    paste(collapse = ",") %>%
    sprintf("[%s]", .) %>%
    fromJSON() %>%
    select(-polyline) %>%
    head()
#>       id                                            name
#> 1 562310        Chicago Amtrak: 225 S Canal St, IL 60606
#> 2 560252            Chicago: 630 W Harrison St, IL 60607
#> 3 561627 Chicago 95th & Dan Ryan: 14 W 95th St, IL 60628
#> 4 260337                   Gary: 100 W 4th Ave, IN 46402
#> 5 260447           Lafayette (e): 401 N 3rd St, IN 47901
#> 6 260392       Indianapolis: 350 S Illinois St, IN 46225
#>                     shortName ticketName category
#> 1          Chicago Amtrak, IL        CHD        2
#> 2                 Chicago, IL        CHD        2
#> 3 Chicago 95th & Dan Ryan, IL        CHD        1
#> 4                    Gary, IN        GRY        2
#> 5           Lafayette (e), IN        XIN        1
#> 6            Indianapolis, IN        IND        2
#>                     linkName direction      lat       lon
#> 1          Chicago_Amtrak_IL     empty 41.87859 -87.63985
#> 2                 Chicago_IL     empty 41.87485 -87.64352
#> 3 Chicago_95th_&_Dan_Ryan_IL     empty 41.72233 -87.62473
#> 4                    Gary_IN     empty 41.60392 -87.33869
#> 5             Lafayette_e_IN     empty 40.42098 -86.89420
#> 6            Indianapolis_IN     empty 39.76178 -86.16102
```